# SQL: Text type with a lot of commonly used values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that basically looks like the following:

```
Timestamp | Service | Observation
----------+---------+------------
...       | vm-1    | 15
...       | vm-1    | 20
...       | vm-1    | 20
...       | vm-1    | 20
...       | vm-1    | 20
...       | vm-1    | 20
...       | bvm-2   | 184
...       | bvm-2   | 104
...       | bvm-2   | 4
...       | bvm-2   | 14
...       | bvm-2   | 657
...       | bvm-2   | 6
...       | bvm-2   | 6
```

The `Service` column will not have a lot of different values. I don't know at table creation time what all possible values are going to be so I can't use an enum, but the number of distinct values are going to grow very slowly at (less than ~10 new distinct values per month or less), whereas I'll have thousands of new observations per day.

Right now I'm just thinking of using a `VARCHAR` or mysql's `TEXT` type for the `Service` column, but given the specifics of the situation those kind of seem wasteful.

Are databases usually smart about this sort of thing? Or is there some way I can hint to the database that this behavior is something that it can reliably exploit?

I'm using MySQL `5.7`. I'd prefer something standards compliant or portable, but I'm also open to MySQL specific workarounds.

---

EDIT:

In other words, what I want is for the column to be treated like an enum, but have the database figure out dynamically based on the data that shows up in the table what the different enum values are.

Comment: A `varchar()` is the right way to store a string.  I'm rather befuddled by what your question is.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If I store as a VARCHAR, and there are a million entries with exactly the same value for that column, say `some-really-long-name`, it'll store a million copies of that same value right (maybe I'm wrong, if so, this is a silly question)? I'd like to hint to the database that you can treat it like an enum, except it'll have to figure out what the enum values are. I can specify some limit on the maximum number of different values they can take.

Comment: Seeing the data I think you should create a separate table for the services and use a foreign key that gets the service_id, with that approach you're getting normalized your tables and you only have one row for each service instead of having the same value repeated.

Comment: @GenaroMorales Ah thanks, that actually seems like "the right thing". I'd still like to explore a bit whether there are simpler ways of indicating to the database what I want, because I'd actually rather not be doing all the book keeping of what values are possible myself.

Comment: As per my answer below you need very little bookkeeping and it can easily be isolated to a stored proc and a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you need to use an `enum` you should consider creating another table and reference to it. It's basic normalization. So create one table for the `ServiceType` with a `name` and an `id` field the `name` can be `VARCHAR` and the `id` should be `INT`. The actual table then just uses the `id` instead of the service name.

You can write a simple stored procedure to do the inserting and looking up of duplicate names as well as a view to access the results so outside of the DB you barely know how it is internally handled.

Your stored procedure needs to:

- Check if the service exists and insert it if not. `INSERT IGNORE ...` is probably your friend here.
- Get the ID of the service with `SELECT id INTO @serv_id FROM ServiceType WHERE name = [service_name];`
- Insert into the table with the service ID instead of the service.

Don't over optimize. MySQL does not store `TINYINT` more efficiently than `INT` so just use the latter and it won't fail until you have billions of services.

Answer (score 0):

I think , you have to create a new table for store the services and and then this table primary key (service_id) can be replaced in place of service text. But main table service column should be int type for storing the service id . So please change the service column type to int(4) .

hope it will be helpfull